# What is the meaning of 'He rested for final qualifier'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading some sports news articles and one of them was titled like this

> '(player name) rested for final Portugal qualifier'.

So here now I am not sure about what they mean by that.

Confusion is...

The player was on rest on that match day **or** he did take rest before that happened so he can perform well in that match?

Comment: could you provide us with the link? I'm **pretty** sure that here, 'rested' means the player is kept out. In fact in most of such cases of sports, it is what I said. What's the player's name>

Comment: @MaulikV I agree that it's likely that it'll be the coach's decision in team sports, and thus the player will be kept out (or will sit out, that is he or she won't play that game). However, the real question the OP asks, imho, is "which game" the player will sit out: the final Portugal qualifier game, or some other games (so that he can play well in the final Portugal qualifier).

Comment: @MaulikV After checking real examples, I think your interpretation is quite possible (about 80% of examples of "rested for" I found are about injuries, the player not being in top form, or some other problems, so they'll miss the game(s) that they're "rested for"). More over than that, it's almost always the case if the news is UK news, so it makes sense that you've heard "rested for" only used in that meaning. +1 for asking for the source.

Comment: Just a quick update. I searched a bit more and now have a hunch that a) this usage could be different in different dialects; b) it ("rested for") is much more frequently used in British English (and also in Indian English); and c) when it's in British English, "X will be rested for a match" always (as far as I can tell) means X will miss the match, which supports @Maulik's answer. (Note that this doesn't mean that I'm sure that my points a), b), and c) are true.)

Comment: I read that in MSN news  mobile app, some days ago, which says 'Ronaldo rested for final Portugal qualifier'

Comment: Thanks for providing the name. My assumption is *correct.* I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means the player has been ***kept out*** for whatever reason. In sports, 'rest' often means keeping a player *out of* that match. In cricket, I hear this very very commonly.

In case when you want to say, 'to prepare for a match in a better way', you may say, *"'x' player **took** rest..."*

---

Update after OP revealed the name.

The [original article is here](http://www.goal.com/en-gb/news/7134/euro-2016-qualifying/2015/10/09/16169262/ronaldo-rested-for-final-portugal-qualifier) which says...

> *"...Ronaldo, alongside Tiago and Ricardo Carvalho, will **sit out** Sunday's clash with Serbia."*

Comment: I interpreted this the opposite way. However I'm not too familiar with sports news jargon.

Comment: it's not the opposite way. It's the way I said. @JamesWebster Updated. Please check